# Adding a EF Core 5 context in Linqpad 6 throws Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' error

Tags: c#, linqpad, .net-5

I've taken a EF Core 3.1 project and converted it to EF Core 5. The DLL builds and I can access the data as expected from my application but when I try and access the context from Linqpad 6 I get:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0. The
> system could not find the file specified.'

Any suggestions on what might be causing this only in LinqPad 6?

Comment: Perhaps because LINQPad 6 isn't updated for release version of .Net 5 yet?

Comment: I have just converted EF Core 3.1 project  to EF Core 5 and tried it from LinqPad6. Everything seems fine. Did you refresh your connection after updating? Did you check if you have the last version LinqPad6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in the test [LINQPad beta](https://www.linqpad.net/linqpad6.aspx#beta).

Comment: For future visitors, if you're getting this error now and you're using .NET6, the solution is to upgrade to LinqPad7.